# How can I make a non-existing directory return a 403 on my exchange server

Tags: iis, exchange-2007

I have an exchange 2007 server that when someone tries to hit a page or directory on the server that does not exist, I want a HTTP 403 to be returned.  How can I set that up?

Comment: Why do you want this and not a 404?

Comment: Project requirements state it should be a 403.  Plus, wouldn't it be another layer of security since it would not indicate if a directory even existed or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure a custom 404 handler in IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx) but you also may need to fix any .net [web.configs that might change this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638074/how-can-i-change-the-customerror-configuration-set-by-the-web-config-during-runt). OWA for example already has a global handler in it's web.config.

If you configure the 404 error handlers to be a **URL** so they are redirected to some code and from the code you can return a 403 response to the user. If you [have asp enabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315122/en-us) you use a simple asp script like:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
 Response.Status="403 Forbidden"
 Response.Write "These are not the 404's you're looking for"
%>
```

p.s. if the aim of this config is to limit directory discovery, you will need to point the 403's you are emulating at the same error handler. Also check if IIS is redirecting a /directory request without a / on the end to /directory/ before the 403 is sent, if the directory exists.